# My Reverse Just Went Out/Everything Else Is Fine

Tags: automatic-transmission, gmc, sierra

I have a 2001 GMC 2500HD automatic 6.0 Vortec and the reverse just quit.  All the other gears work fine. Where can I find a video that shows how to solve this?

Comment: Did it simply not work at startup or did some event occur like putting in in reverse while still drifting forward, etc.?

Comment: one day i started it up and when i put it in reverse and nothing happend

Answer (score 2):

You need to check a couple of things.

1. Ensure you have enough transmission fluid in your vehicle.
2. If the fluid is up to par, one of two things could be going wrong (to my knowledge):

   - The reverse band has gone out (less likely)
   - The reverse solenoid has gone out (more likely)

Is there a check engine light showing on the dash? Might not be, but you should still try to read the codes. There could very well be a transmission code which will tell you what's going on. If it is a bad solenoid, it would probably show up here as a DTC. That's going to help you more than us guessing as to what could be your issue.

Comment: I favour the reverse solenoid possibility.  Check out http://www.insanehydraulics.com/letstalk/solenoiddiode.html for testing, @sonierw.